# Let user change Font in Metro app

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, microsoft-metro

You know how in WinForms you can open the Font Dialog or Font Browser (I can't remember anymore) and let the user decide which font they want to read/write in, along with the Size and optional color/weights etc?

How can we do this in Metro Apps? Obviously some fonts are easier to read than others for some, so it only makes sense to let them change it.

But I don't see anything in the Docs about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to use DirectWrite if you want to get a list of available fonts from a Metro app.

See (Microsoft sample): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DirectWrite-font-60e53e0b

Comment: So, we have to implement our own Font selector? Hmmm.